# AngularJS: How can I update the $scope property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an object on the $scope that dictates the "next screen" for the app to go after update (I'm in a wizard-like multi-screen new form) and as each screen is displayed, I want to show the current and all subsequent screens in the sidebar -- easy to go back for the user to make changes but not allowing him/her to skip steps by not displaying future screens.

Of course, it has to be dynamic because the screen order changes for different types of loans.

**My question -- in the controller of the current screen, how do I change the status to true AND make the view recognize the change? (LoDash is available)**

This is a partial of $scope.screens (an array of objects):

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "loantype_id": 2,
    "screen": "farmer",
    "label": "Farmer",
    "sort_order": 1,
    "status": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "loantype_id": 2,
    "screen": "applicant",
    "label": "Applicant",
    "sort_order": 2,
    "status": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "loantype_id": 2,
    "screen": "quests",
    "label": "Questions",
    "sort_order": 3,
    "status": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "loantype_id": 2,
    "screen": "references",
    "label": "References",
    "sort_order": 4,
    "status": 0
  }
]
```

I move from the farmer screen to the applicant screen and I can alert the "applicant" from the state URL -- that value should be able to be used to "find" the right object in $scope.screens but I can't figure it out

This is the pertinent part of ApplicantController -- alert(currScreen) == 'applicant':

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
      .module('ARM')
      .controller('NewApplicantController', function(
        $scope, $state, $stateParams, Loan,
        AppFactory, ApplicantsFactory
      ){
        var curr = $state.current.url;
        var currScreen = curr.substring(1,curr.length);
        alert(currScreen);

        $scope.loan = Loan.data.data[0];

        if($scope.loan.applicant_id) {
          ApplicantsFactory.getApplicant($scope.loan.applicant_id)
            .then(function success(rsp) {
              $scope.applicant = rsp.data.data;
              $scope.applicant.entity_type_id = '2';
            });
        } else {
          $scope.applicant = { entity_type_id: '2' };
        } // end if

        $scope.createApplicant = function() {
          ApplicantsFactory.createApplicant($scope.applicant)
            .then(function(rsp){
              AppFactory.patchIt('/loans/', $stateParams.loanID, {applicant_id: rsp.data.message});
              AppFactory.moveToNextNewLoanScreen(currScreen, $stateParams);
            });
        };
      });
})();
```

Comment: Where exactly is it breaking down. Is `currScreen` undefined?

Comment: no, currScreen (in this case) alerts 'applicant'... I just don't know HOW to refer to the object to change the status to 1 ... I tried $scope.screens[0].currScreen.status = 1: $scope.$apply() but that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be because based on the array of screens that you referenced above, 'currScreen' is undefined? By this I mean '$scope.screens[0].currScreen' does not exist so you can't assign '$scope.screens[0].currScreen.status = 1'.

Comment: very possibly could be but I don't know how to change that status ... is there a better way to set it up (I hope not because the hard part -- that is, the dynamic navigation -- works fine. I just need a way to "turn on" the current screen in the navigation.

Comment: If you are talking about adding currScreen to your model then two ways are possible. Either you instantiate the $scope.screens to have a currScreen property in each object or instead of doing '$scope.screens[0].currScreen.status = 1' you do '$scope.screens[0].currScreen = {status : 1}'